# Synchronized windows explorer folder browsing

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for some software which will allow me to perform synchronized browsing between 3 different windows machines.

FileZilla has a synchronized browsing feature in which you declare a base directory on both the server and locally. This allows you to traverse your filesystem and quickly move files to or from the server without doing double-duty in terms of navigation.

---

I am faced with a situation where I constantly need to keep my local machine and two servers in sync so I would like to know if there is anything which would support the following features:

- Open 3 explorer windows side-by-side (local and two servers)
- Declare a root dir across three machines
- Opening a folder inside of any explorer would cause the others to do likewise (synchronized browsing)
- Drag-n-drop files between the explorer windows

Would be nice:

- Allow me to save profiles which I can simply click and connect to all the explorer windows

---

I have looked into [Windows Double Explorer](https://wde.codeplex.com/) but the short-comings are as follows:

- Only two side-by-side explorer panes
- Tabs are supported but these are inefficient for what I need
- No synchronized browsing

---

I have also looked at [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) but their home page clearly states `Two file windows side by side`

---

One important note is that yes I am aware of automation software which can keep directories and files synced but I am not currently interested in implementing something automatic or else I would have done so by now.

I am looking to perform my syncs manually.

Answer (score 2):

[FreeCommander](http://freecommander.com/) will allow you to accomplish your goal.

It doesn't do it *exactly* how you want, but it has sufficient functionality to get the job done.  It allows synchronized browsing.  It also allows opening new locations automatically synchronized to an existing location.

The big downside for you is that it only has 2 panes, not 3.  That's not ideal for you, but clever use of folder tabs makes it almost as good.  You can drag and drop directly onto any tab just like it was a separate pane.

It allows declaring a root dir across all the systems, has drag and drop, and even allows you to save profiles.  It is *very* flexible.

It's not a perfect match for what you need, but it comes close enough that hopefully it will be helpful to you.

---

***UPDATE:***
After losing important data due to FreeCommander bugs, I can no longer recommend this application.  The developer simply does not perform adequate testing before releases, and does not have any dedicated QA testers.  This application has great potential, but overall the project needs a much higher level of QC to recommend it universally.

Comment: HOW does FreeCommander do this? I haven't found this functionality anywhere.

Comment: @SsjCosty It is the menuitem that begins with *Link* in the *Folder* menu.  Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

FileCommander

http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=516
or
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/FileCommander.shtml

File manager with support for up to four panes at a time, integrating an MD5 checksum creator, file splitting and synchronization tools, and others

The main application window contains four tree views by default, and you can switch to one, two, or three panes.

From the "Extras" menu you can view currently active processes, installed software and drivers, open a DOS command window, split or synchronize files, use a search function with file masks, as well as add or remove virtual hard drives.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately this software lacks the key feature of synchronized browsing across different computers. I did find the View->Match Windows but unfortunately it does not perform in the way I described. Thank you.